# ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1024

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
d = 2
R_1 = np.arange(0, 20)
R_2 = np.arange(0,20)
N_1 = 1024
N_2 = 1024
n_1 = np.arange(0, N_1)
n_2 = np.arange(0, N_2)


for i in n_1:
    x_1 = -0.5 * R_1 + n_1[i] * R_1/N_1
    for j in n_2:
        x_2 = -0.5 * R_2 + n_2[j] * R_2/N_2
```

I want to create a matrix of size N_1 by N_2

```
Rho = np.zeros(n_1, n_2)
for i in N_1:
    for j in N_2:
        Rho = [np.exp(-np.linalg.norm (x_1) ** 2), np.exp(-np.linalg.norm (x_2) ** 2)]
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: i am getting this error "ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1024"

Comment: `Rho = np.zeros((N_1, N_2))`, `for i in n_1:`, `for j in n_2:`, you mixed up the `ranges` and `values` variables. Please always include the entire error trace. The re-assignment of *Rho* inside the loop seems not correct.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny i want to evaluate `Rho = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm (X) ** 2)` where X is a vector of `x_1` and `x_2`

Comment: You forgot to tell us which line raised the error!  We can guess it is the `np.zeros(n_1, n_2)`.  If so, did you spend any time (re)reading the `np.zeros` docs?  Did you review the arguments you passed it, the `n_1` and `n_2`?

Comment: Thanks@hpaulj 
i figured out the first error with the help of what @MichaelSzczesny and now what i want to do now is `Rho = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm (X) ** 2)` where `X` is a vector of `x_1` and `x_2`